# Laravel Nested Relationship on Factory for Testing

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-5

I got a problem, i have to admit i don't find any solution.
I'm actually developping some testing for functionnalities and Factories are blocking me.

First I'm trying to add with factories an Entity called "Tasklist" which contains one or many "sections" which contains one or many "actions".
I have a 3 level deep relationship.

Here are my factories:

```
    $factory->define(\App\V2\Models\Tasklist::class, function (\Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'id_course'        => \App\V2\Models\Program::all()->random(1)->id,
        'id_event'         => \App\V2\Models\Stage::all()->random(1)->id,
        'id_course_rounds' => \App\V2\Models\ProgramRound::all()->random(1)->id,
        'name'             => $faker->word,
        'display_name'     => $faker->word,
        'color'            => 0,
        'key'              => str_random(16),
        'auto_active'      => 1,
        'status'           => 1,
    ];
});

$factory->define(\App\V2\Models\TasklistSection::class, function (\Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'id_tasklist' => function(){
            return factory(\App\V2\Models\Tasklist::class)->create()->id;
        },
        'number'      => 1,
        'title'       => $faker->word,
        'text'        => $faker->text(100),
        'status'      => 1
    ];
});

$factory->define(\App\V2\Models\TasklistAction::class, function(\Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'id_tasklists_section' => factory(\App\V2\Models\TasklistSection::class)->create()->id,
        'number' => rand(1, 10),
        'title' => $faker->word,
        'percent' => $faker->numberBetween(0, 100),
        'status' => 1
    ];
});
```

In my testing class, i'm trying to generate a tasklist with 1 section with one action. The only way i found actually was something like that:

```
$task = factory(Tasklist::class, 2)->create()
            ->each(function($t){
               $t->sections()->save(factory(TasklistSection::class)->create()
                   ->each(function($s){
                     $s->actions()->save(factory(TasklistAction::class)->create());
                   })
               );
            });
```

To this code, if I delete the second each, it works, i got 2 tasklists with each 1 sections. In fact, the each is disturbing me.

I would like to create only one tasklist, with one or several sections with one or several actions on it.

But the each only accept Collection input the save method accepts only model input and not collection.

Does somebody have an idea how to deal with that ?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Yes i put each factory alone with a return of the id of the parent container.
factory for tasklists return the id, then i create 2 sections with this takslist id and then 5 action withing the section etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Seeding Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449226/laravel-seeding-relationships)

Answer (score 1):

One approach can be this:
create task with sections and store them in the variable and then loop through each task section and add actions to it like this:

```
$tasklist = factory(App\Tasklist::class)->create();
$tasklist->sections()->saveMany(factory(App\TasklistSection::class, 3)->make());

foreach ($tasklist->sections as $section){
  $section->actions()->saveMany(factory(App\TasklistAction::class, 3)->make());
}
```

this will work as expected.