# Seeding with chained relationship in Laravel 5.7

Tags: database, laravel, seeding

I have a `User, Company` and `BusinessUnit` model, already created the relationships and I want to do database seeding using model factory with this condition:

> 1. Each User has one Company
> 2. Each Company belongs to a User and has many BusinessUnit
> 3. Each BusinessUnit belongs to a Company

I created this code to seed the `Company` and it's working

```
factory(App\User::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($user) {
    $user->company()->saveMany(
        factory(App\Company::class, 5)->make()
    );
});
```

But when I try to add `BusinessUnit` like this:

```
factory(App\User::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($user) {
    $user->company()->saveMany(
        factory(App\Company::class, 5)->make()->each(function ($company) {
            $company->businessUnit()->saveMany(
                factory(App\BusinessUnit::class, 50)->make()
            );
        })
    );
});
```

I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'company_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `business_units`
>   (`icon`, `name`, `description`, `address`, `company_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (//via.placeholder.com/150, Aspernatur consectetur quia vitae., Odio natus et eaque aut neque. Corrupti illo optio aut quas reiciendis est. Officiis doloribus vitae aliquam cupiditate dolor., 4300 Bartell Fords
>   Elijahton, TX 34915-7562, , 2018-12-27 11:24:42, 2018-12-27 11:24:42))

Is there any proper way to do it? I already read the documentation but still have no clue about it. Please help.

Comment: Please check this two links \n
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449226/laravel-seeding-relationships \n

https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-two-ways-seed-data-relationships/

Comment: This upcoming change will be perfect for you: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26811

Comment: @Shibon I followed your link recommendation and still not working for the bussiness unit seeding

Comment: @Shibon , I do re checking for your first link and found the solution. I will post it as the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: ur question is duplicate please don't post it as answer

Comment: oh okay, i will remove it

Comment: @Shibon What is the duplicate question ?

Comment: @ljas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449226/laravel-seeding-relationships this question is similar

Comment: Yes similar, not duplicate. This guy has a different issue.

Comment: note that make() just creates an eloquent model and not persist it on database so the ID field remains empty whilst create() will save the new model to DB and gets its primary key back, so first you have to create() the company models, then try to saveMany Business on each of those

Comment: yes I know the differences about make() and create(). When I use create, it produce new error. But I already fixed that. Should I undelete my answer? I think it would be useful for a newcomers which have similar problem with my question. Knowing that there is no marked answer on the link provided by @Shibon. What do you guys think?

Comment: anyways, my answer is close enough  to @Ijas 's. I think undeleting my answer isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Companies should be created before assigning Business Units. In your code, you are not creating companies, but just making array of company objects and trying to associate business units with them.

Try this,

```
factory(App\User::class, 5)->create()->each(function ($user) {
    $user->company()->saveMany(
        factory(App\Company::class, 5)->create(['user_id' => $user->id])->each(function ($company) {
            $company->businessUnit()->saveMany(
                factory(App\BusinessUnit::class, 50)->make()
            );
        })
    );
});
```