# Laravel 5.8 - Seeding a ManyToOne relationship

Tags: php, laravel, factory, seeding, faker

Evening everyone,

I'm looking forward to seed my **Post Table** within my **Category Table** through a foreign key, **category_id**, inside my Post Table.

But unfortunately I encounter an issue I do not manage to deal with, and this is why I am requesting your help

---

**Here are my Models** :

**Post** :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

/**
 * @method static create(array $array)
 */
class Post extends Model
{

   use SoftDeletes;

   protected $fillable = ['title', 'description', 'contenu', 'image', 'published_at', 'category_id'];


   /**
    * Delete image from storage
    */
    public function deleteImage()
    {
      Storage::delete($this->image);
    }

    // OneToMany(Inverse)
    public function category()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
    }

    // ManyToMany
    public function tags()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
    }


    /**
     * Check if a post has tag.
     * tags return a collection, if we want to get the id from the array
     * we must use the pluck function
     * @param $id
     * @return bool
     */
     public function hasTag($id)
     {
       return in_array($id, $this->tags->pluck('id')->toArray());
     }
}
```

**Category**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * @method static create(array $all)
 */
class Category extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['name'];

  // OneToMany
  public function posts()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
  }
}
```

**Here are my Factories** :

**Post**

```
<?php

/* @var $factory \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory */

use App\Category;
use App\Post;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$factory->define(Post::class, function (Faker $faker) {

$image = $faker->image();
$imageFile = new File($image);

return [
    'title' => 'hello',
    'description' => $faker->text(100),
    'contenu' => $faker->text(100),
    'image' => Storage::disk('public')->putFile('posts', $imageFile),
    'published_at' => $faker->date('Y-m-d'),
    'category_id' => factory('App\Category')->create()->id,
    // 'category_id' => $faker->numberBetween(1,5)
];
});
```

**Category**

```
<?php

/* @var $factory \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory */

use App\Category;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'name' => $faker->words(5, true),
    'image' => $faker->imageUrl()
];
});
```

**My Seeder**

```
<?php

use App\Post;
use App\Tag;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class PostTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
  /**
   * Run the database seeds.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function run()
  {
    /**
     * MANY TO MANY
     */
    $posts = factory(Post::class, 15)->create(); // 1.
    $tags = factory(Tag::class, 10)->create(); // 2
    $posts
        ->each(function (Post $posts) use ($tags) {
            $posts->tags()->attach(
                $tags->random(rand(1, 10))->pluck('id')->toArray() // 3.
            );
        });
   }
}
```

---

I know that through a hasMany relationship, you can do it this way :

```
factory(User::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($user) {
$user->posts()->saveMany(factory(Posts::class, 5)->make());
});
```

Or this way :

```
//create 10 users
factory(User::class, 10)->create()->each(function ($user) {
//create 5 posts for each user
factory(Post::class, 5)->create(['user_id'=>$user->id]);
});
```

With a User and a Post Model connected each others : [Laravel - Seeding Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449226/laravel-seeding-relationships)

---

I also know that, if you add this :

```
'category_id' => factory('App\Category')->create()->id,
```

To your factory it will generate category_id fields, according to the number of posts you asked.

So it means that if you asked for 5 posts, it will generate you 5 category_id number from 1 to 5 : which also means 5 new categories on your database.

Then if you ask for 50 posts, you will get 50 new categories..

This is not what I am looking for.

---

So my question is this,

How can I make it that, I can add **the desired** number of the category I want, along with, **the desired** number of the posts I want?

So that both tables are still linked together in the database.

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
    $table
        ->foreign('category_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('categories')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
```

---

If you look at my **Post Factory**, you will see this commented :

```
 // 'category_id' => $faker->numberBetween(1,5)
```

I know that through this way, by generating a random number, with a maximum value **equals to the number of the categories I want** :

```
   factory(Category::class, 5)->create();
```

It will give me a random number between 1 and 5 for my category_id, and at the same time, get me my desired number of categories I requested.

So my posts won't have a linear category_id (1,2,3,4,5), but it will be shuffled to random.

Which is what I am looking for as well.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the answer to your own question.  I would just create the number of **Category** objects you want (say 5).  Do this first.

```
factory(Category::class, 5)->create();
```

Now that you have these, if this is your first migration, you can just add them randomly like you have it in your Post factory model:

```
return [
    'title' => 'hello',
    // .. etc.
    'category_id' => $faker->numberBetween(1,5)
];
```

However, if you already have values for the **Category** ids, or you may add more or change them later, and want to use the factory for future **Posts** outside of the original migration, you can get the current category ids and then inject them randomly into the post `category_id` field in the same factory:

```
$cat_ids = Category::pluck('id', 'id')->toArray();

 return [
    'title' => 'hello',
    // .. etc.
    'category_id' => array_rand($cat_ids, 1)
];
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I with I will as you said stick on my way, but add this "array_rand($cat_ids, 1)" tip, very nice. 

Spend a good day/evening.