# How to seed related data during migration in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-migrations, laravel-seeding

I have a table `clients` and a table `contracts`.
In my `Client` model I have

```php
public function contract()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(
            'App\Models\Contract',
            'client_id',
            'id'
        );
    }
```

I don't want to have any client without a contract in my database.
When I seed my clients, using the factory with faker data, I want to create contracts that are mapped to client using the foreign key user_id on the contract.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44462235/9636400

Comment: Yes it does, thank you. In my case it is `save()` instead of `saveMany()`, but I already tested it and it is working. Quick question to learn to avoid asking duplicate questions in the future, because I searched a solution before I asked. Did I need to know that this is called "Seeding Relationships"?

Comment: Would help for being more specific in searches. Is it a must? No. probably not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```php
App\Models\Client::factory(10)->create()->each(function ($client) {
    $client->contract()->save(Contract::factory()->make());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure to make a factory for each table and then you can simply do something like

```
        Client::factory()
        ->count(3)
        ->has(Contract::factory()->forUser()->create())
        ->create();
```

Notice: check your relations in your models then it should be fine :)